# CSS - Display property not working with an img

Tags: jquery, css

I have a "speech bubble". I build it using a div for the content. In that div I put an img that I used for the tail. Those 2 are hidden when the page loads. When a certain button is clicked, those 2 are supposed to be displayed. Nevertheless only the content(#msg-loc) is displayed. The img remains hidden. And I don't get it. The strange thing is that if I remove the hidden property by default, everything is dispalyed properly. Does the display property not work with img? Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

My HTML:

```
<div id="msg-loc" class="hidden">
    <img src="img/triangle.png" class="hidden triangle"/>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$('#msg-loc').html('the value is incorrect').removeClass('hidden');
$('.triangle').removeClass('hidden');
```

My CSS:

```
#msg-loc{
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:8px;
    background-color:pink;}

.triangle{
    left:65px;
    top:-13px;
    position:relative;}

.hidden{
    display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the image with 'the value is incorrect'.

Based on comments... updated solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/P7yhz/3/

HTML

```
   <div id="msg-loc" class="hidden">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="message">The value is incorrect</div>
</div>
<a href="#">Reveal</a>
```

CSS

```
#msg-loc{
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:8px;
}

.triangle {
    background:url('http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/images/regular-triangle-sm.gif') no-repeat bottom center;
    height: 40px;
}
.message {background:pink;}

.hidden{
    display:none;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('#msg-loc').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
```

});

Comment: The problem the prepend() is incrementing every time i click on the button. Is there an opposite function of prepend?

Comment: Personally, I'd also drop the image and use it as a background-image for an "error" span or div.

Comment: Based on my previous comment... a slight reworking of the error prompt: http://jsfiddle.net/P7yhz/3/

Comment: This sounds good. Better than my idea. Nevertheless is it possible to put the arrow (img) above text and centered horizontally?Thks

Comment: You drive a hard bargain! ;)  No, you couldn't have it above because the background would also be pink under it. (The trick would've been background -> center top + padding equal to the image's height).  Rather, I split your need in two : http://jsfiddle.net/P7yhz/4/  (The spacing between the arrow and the block is because the image's bottom isn't flush. Get an image that's properly cropped and you'll be in business)

Comment: Edited my answer above. Also, this way, if ever you need custom error messages, you can simply $('#msg-loc .message').html('Custom error message');

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I already feel my knowledge growing :) Cheers... Tabernacle !

Answer (score 0):

By using the `$('#msg-loc').html('the value is incorrect').removeClass('hidden');` you completely delete whats inside the #msg-loc div. And after it is empty you remove its class "hidden".

This is done by the .html function.

A solution will be.

```
var x = document.createTextNode("the value is incorrect");
$('#msg-loc').append(x);
$('#msg-loc').removeClass('hidden');
$('.triangle').removeClass('hidden');​
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the html part of your code

```
<div id="msg-loc" class="hidden">
    <img src="Icons/Apps_icons/eye.png" id="yo" class="hidden triangle"/>
</div> 
<a href="#" id="t">Click Me</a>
```

This is the JavaScript part

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#t").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("div#msg-loc").removeClass("hidden");
            $("img#yo").removeClass("hidden");
            }); 
        });
```

I just added an "id" to the "img" tag and an Anchor tag which provides the function to be called. And I think so your CSS is correct.

Comment: Hello Prateek. Thanks for the help. I choose the solution proposed by Isotrope...

Comment: @Mark: No problem friend I also prefer that solution, but I just suggested an alternative.......thanks for the response.